# vanilla and chokolate cake producing and consuming by waiter in c++ using semaphore mutex in ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu

In my problem two chef, chef x will produce chokolate cake, chef y will produce vanilla cake. There are 5 slots queue0 to put cakes. When slots are full they will take break. Chef z will take cake from this slots and puts vanilla cake in queue1 and chokolate cake in queue2. Waiter 1 takes cake from queue1 and waiter 2 take cakes from queue2. When queue0 is not full chef x and chef y starts making cake. I wrote a code. But it shows that chef y can produce 4 vanilla cake then the code stuck and no further output is showing.

Here is my Code

```
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include<semaphore.h>
    //#include </usr/include/semaphore.h>

    // for sleep
    #include <unistd.h>

    #define BUFF_SIZE   5           /* total number of slots */

    typedef struct                //Producing queue
    {
        char buf1[BUFF_SIZE];   /* shared var */
        int in1;               /* buf[in%BUFF_SIZE] is the first empty slot */
        int out1;              /* buf[out%BUFF_SIZE] is the first full slot */
        sem_t full;           /* keep track of the number of full spots */
        sem_t empty;          /* keep track of the number of empty spots */

        // use correct type here
        pthread_mutex_t mutex;          /* enforce mutual exclusion to shared data */
    } sbuf_t1;

    typedef struct               //Chokolate Cake queue
    {
        char buf2[BUFF_SIZE];   /* shared var */
        int in2;               /* buf[in%BUFF_SIZE] is the first empty slot */
        int out2;              /* buf[out%BUFF_SIZE] is the first full slot */
        sem_t full;           /* keep track of the number of full spots */
        sem_t empty;          /* keep track of the number of empty spots */

        // use correct type here
        pthread_mutex_t mutex;          /* enforce mutual exclusion to shared data */
    } sbuf_t2;

    typedef struct               //Vanilla Cake queue
    {
        char buf3[BUFF_SIZE];   /* shared var */
        int in3;               /* buf[in%BUFF_SIZE] is the first empty slot */
        int out3;              /* buf[out%BUFF_SIZE] is the first full slot */
        sem_t full;           /* keep track of the number of full spots */
        sem_t empty;          /* keep track of the number of empty spots */

        // use correct type here
        pthread_mutex_t mutex;          /* enforce mutual exclusion to shared data */
    } sbuf_t3;

    sbuf_t1 shared1;
    sbuf_t2 shared2;
    sbuf_t3 shared3;


    void *Producer1(void *arg)
    {
        int i, index;
        char item;

        index = (int)arg;

        for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
        {
            sem_wait(&shared1.empty);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&shared1.mutex);
            sleep(1);
            shared1.buf1[shared1.in1] = 'C';
            shared1.in1 = (shared1.in1+1)%BUFF_SIZE;
            printf("[P%d] Producing Chokolate Cake...\n", index);
            fflush(stdout);
            /* Release the buffer */
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared1.mutex);
            /* Increment the number of full slots */
            sem_post(&shared1.full);
            //if (i % 2 == 1) sleep(1);
        }


        return NULL;
    }


    void *Producer2(void *arg)
    {
        int i, index;
        char item;

        index = (int)arg;

        for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
        {
            item = i;
            sem_wait(&shared1.empty);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&shared1.mutex);
            sleep(1);
            shared1.buf1[shared1.in1] = 'V';
            shared1.in1 = (shared1.in1+1)%BUFF_SIZE;
            printf("[P%d] Producing Vanilla Cake...\n", index);
            fflush(stdout);
            /* Release the buffer */
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared1.mutex);
            /* Increment the number of full slots */
            sem_post(&shared1.full);
            //if (i % 2 == 1) sleep(1);
        }


        return NULL;
    }


    void *Chef_Z(void *arg)
    {
        int i, index;
        char item;

        index = (int)arg;

        for (i=10; i > 0; i--) {
            sem_wait(&shared1.full);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&shared1.mutex);
            sleep(1);
            item=shared1.buf1[shared1.out1];
            if(item == 'C')  // Chokolate Cake queue
            {
            sem_wait(&shared2.full);
                pthread_mutex_lock(&shared2.mutex);
                shared2.buf2[shared2.in2]=item; 
                shared2.in2 = (shared2.in2+1)%BUFF_SIZE;
            printf("[C_Z] Consuming  Chokolate Cake and stored it in Chokolate queue ...\n");
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared2.mutex);
                /* Increment the number of full slots */
                sem_post(&shared2.empty);

            }
            else if(item == 'V')  // Vanilla Cake queue
            {
            sem_wait(&shared3.full);
                pthread_mutex_lock(&shared3.mutex);
                shared3.buf3[shared3.in3]=item; 
                shared3.in3 = (shared3.in3+1)%BUFF_SIZE;
            printf("[C_Z] Consuming  Vanilla Cake and stored it in Vanilla queue ...\n");
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared3.mutex);
                /* Increment the number of full slots */
                sem_post(&shared3.empty);

            }
            shared1.out1 = (shared1.out1+1)%BUFF_SIZE;

            fflush(stdout);
            /* Release the buffer */
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared1.mutex);
            /* Increment the number of full slots */
            sem_post(&shared1.empty);

            /* Interleave  producer and consumer execution */
            //if (i % 2 == 1) sleep(1);
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    void *Waiter1(void *arg) //Chokolate cake waiter
    {
        int i, index;
        char item;

        index = (int)arg;

        for (i=10; i > 0; i--) {
            sem_wait(&shared2.full);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&shared2.mutex);
            sleep(1);

            item=shared2.buf2[shared2.out2];
            shared2.out2 = (shared2.out2+1)%BUFF_SIZE;
            printf("[W%d] Consuming  Chokolate Cake ...\n", index);
            fflush(stdout);
            /* Release the buffer */
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared2.mutex);
            /* Increment the number of full slots */
            sem_post(&shared2.empty);

            /* Interleave  producer and consumer execution */
            //if (i % 2 == 1) sleep(1);
        }
        return NULL;
    }


    void *Waiter2(void *arg)  // Vanilla cake waiter
    {
        int i, index;
        char item;

        index = (int)arg;

        for (i=10; i > 0; i--) {
            sem_wait(&shared3.full);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&shared3.mutex);
            sleep(1);

            item=shared3.buf3[shared3.out3];
            shared3.out3 = (shared3.out3+1)%BUFF_SIZE;
            printf("[W%d] Consuming  Vanilla Cake ...\n", index);
            fflush(stdout);
            /* Release the buffer */
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared3.mutex);
            /* Increment the number of full slots */
            sem_post(&shared3.empty);

            /* Interleave  producer and consumer execution */
            //if (i % 2 == 1) sleep(1);
        }

        return NULL;
    }


    int main()
    {
        //pthread_t idP, idC;
        pthread_t thread1,thread2,thread3,thread4,thread5;
        int index;

        void *producer1End;
        void *producer2End;
        void *chef_zEnd;
        void *waiter1End;
        void *waiter2End;

        sem_init(&shared1.full, 0, 0);
        sem_init(&shared1.empty, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
        pthread_mutex_init(&shared1.mutex, NULL);

        sem_init(&shared2.full, 0, 0);
        sem_init(&shared2.empty, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
        pthread_mutex_init(&shared2.mutex, NULL);

        sem_init(&shared3.full, 0, 0);
        sem_init(&shared3.empty, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
        pthread_mutex_init(&shared3.mutex, NULL);

        pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, Producer1, (void*)1 );
        pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, Producer2, (void*)2 );
        pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, Chef_Z, (void*)1 );    

        pthread_create(&thread4, NULL, Waiter1, (void*)1);
        pthread_create(&thread5, NULL, Waiter2, (void*)2);

        pthread_join(thread1,&producer1End);
        pthread_join(thread2,&producer2End);
        pthread_join(thread3,&chef_zEnd);
        pthread_join(thread4,&waiter1End);
        pthread_join(thread5,&waiter2End);

        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I am unable to find problem with my code. Why it's not working. Can you help me to solve this problem

Comment: I've had a look at your code and find the variable names you've chosen make it rather difficult to read. I also noticed that the `struct`s that you typedef are identical. You should just declare 1 for clarity and additionally, rename `shared1`, `shared2` and `shared3` with more meaningful names. In order to solve your problem, I suggest you use `printf` statements so you know when a particular block of code is executed.

Comment: same problem occur again. It stuck after producing 4 vanilla cake. I don't understand why it's happening

Comment: I suggest again that you place extra printf statements in your code. If you place enough of them (or put a few in the right spots) you'll soon be able to identify where execution gets stuck. Places I suggest to put such `printf` statements include. **a** the start of a function **b** the end of a function **c** before any loop **d** inside any if blocks. A useful statement can be: `printf("(%d) %s\n", __LINE__, __FILE__);`, which will print the line-number and source-file name. Using this same line provides clarity - you know exactly which line of code produces output on screen. :)

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. It helps me.